# Avoiding using Expletives in titles

Tags: discussion, title

I think that we should limit expletives on our site, or at least with titles. I think that a few inappropriate words tucked away might be appropriate at times. However, in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/260/pronunciation-of-beaches-and-bitches), it is used in the title. I think this looks somewhat un-professional, personally. Perhaps in titles We should use asterisks to accomplish this.

Also according to [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites/), expletives are not allowed anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some – like my English professor in college who also happened to raise dogs – might argue that *bitches* is not really an expletive in and of itself (even though it does have an [offensive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bitch) usage).

The easiest way to fix the question you link to, though, would be to simply replace the letter *b* with the letter *p*:

> Pronunciation of “peaches” and “pitches”

(I assume that would be asking the same question, essentially.)

All that said, if I were writing a question, I’d avoid using expletives or patently offensive words in the title. That just seems like a common sense courtesy.

Comment: Agreed, that seems like a great idea. And yes I agree, it doesn't bug me, but titles are seen on google more then anything else...

Comment: The distinction is whether the word is essential to a question asked in good faith, or is it just gratuitous grandstanding just to attract attention.